# Member vector of objects (not pointers) gets 'unset' after the pointer to (global/persisting) object goes out of scope

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, parameter-passing, visibility

Would someone please take a look at the following code fragments (all from one file) and advise on the problem I will describe at the end?

members:

```
    std::vector<cHasAMyClass>   collected;
    std::vector<cHasACHasAMyClass>  memberVector;//Actually an array of vectors, but simpler not to be.
```

constructor of an inner/local class:

```
    cHasACHasAMyClass(cHasAMyClass *ptrToCHasAMyC, int stuff) :
                masterRef(ptrToCHasAMyC),
                other_stuff(stuff) {}
```

method I was using:

```
cHasAMyClass *firstUniqueOccurrence(std::vector<cHasAMyClass> *masterList, myClass *qSq) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)masterList->size(); ++i)
        if ((*masterList)[i].myClassPtr == qSq) return &((*masterList)[i]);
    masterList->push_back(cHasAMyClass(qSq));
    return &(masterList->back());
}
```

block which calls above method:

```
{
    std::vector<myClass *> allAtLoc;
    if (map->getAllHere(curLoc, &allAtLoc)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)allAtLoc.size(); ++i) {
            int stuff = 42; //Or otherwise
            cHasAMyClass *newContainer = firstUniqueOccurrence(&(collected), allAtLoc[i]);
            memberVector.push_back(cHasACHasAMyClass(newContainer, stuff));
        }
    }
    allAtLoc.clear();
}
```

Problem is sometime later (ok prolly immediately on leaving the above block) `memberVector[0].masterRef` appears messed up which I detect (apart from crashing) because its member of type `myClass` is invalid or null. I thought I had set it to a pointer to persisting object (managed in another data structure, a simple array (/ptr - it's `new`/`malloc`'d)) but I'm new to using vectors and not sure what sort of indirection I was witnessing.

I have `allAtLoc` and `newContainer` going out of scope and though they are but pointers to objects, they have side effects. Incidentally, my `collected` vector doesn't contain errors.

This was all working fine before I made the move to `std::vector`s, I don't understand how my indirection is wrong, please could someone advise?

Comment: can you show the working code before vectors? will help detect any wrong conversions.

Comment: only got code for `myClass **map->getAllHere(` persisting in this source, I'd need to search earlier archives for the alternative code to the above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to read your code, but it looks like you are taking pointers to elements within a `vector`. Pointers, iterators and references to a `vector` are invalidated when its capacity changes. That can happen as a side effect of any function that inserts into the `vector`, since a new bigger internal array is created into which the current contents are copyed.

If you want to use pointers to elements in a `vector`, you have to make sure they won't be invalidated. If you know the number of elements, you could call `reserve` prior to inserting any elements.

Comment: Elements are persisted using a standard pointer to `new`'d alloc'd memory, as my update just added. Ah, now I see what you mean, calling `masterList->push_back` invalidates any references I may have previously made to it! `vector` is not such a labour saver after all! I was observing mostly the first elements being corrupted, which is slightly odd since I'd expect the memory to remain contiguous. I'd have to better check for more subtle corruption though.

Comment: @John: It's precisely because the memory remains contiguous that pointers are invalidated.

Comment: yes but wouldn't that invalidate all contiguous elements, I found {bad line=0, ok line=1,2,4,5,6 ok+bad line=3} but I didn't check all that thoroughly. As I don't know the size, are you suggesting I should revert to `new` and pointers?

Comment: @John: When pointers, references and iterators are invalidated is documented and guaranteed by the standard. Do some research on the subject. If using `vector` to replace a C-style array then just call `reserve(size)` after initializing it.